# How to remove padding top and bottom to set height and width

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

How to remove the nest paddings to get exactly height and width in a div that contains others div inside. I'm using Tailwind and this UI.

[daisyUI](https://daisyui.com/)

[image]

The margin top and margin bottom doesn't fit. Even if I use the vh or/and wh units, and other tips.

Answer (score 0):

If you could elaborate what you are looking for, that will be great! You can start with using this * symbol for removing inbuilt margin and padding in elements in your stylesheets.

```
*{
   margin:0
   padding:0

  }
```

This should remove any padding or margins for all elements including the nested elements and you will get their exact height and width. The height will be the font-size and width will be the screen size without any margin or padding.

Comment: Thanks, I Will go yo try and tell later

Comment: Doesn't work, remove all space, but I need this to separate the div. Check the question again, I change the image